# Two columns in a row in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I want to iterate two columns in a row ...

```
@Html.Partial("_MediumProductWrap", product)
```

is a column

```
@foreach (var product in Model.Products)
{
    <div class="row">
        @Html.Partial("_MediumProductWrap", product) // Col
    </div>
}
```

Comment: It should work if you put the "row" div outside the foreach loop. Then make sure that your partial has a class of `col-6`, which will cause them to appear as two columns (presuming that you're using bootstrap).

Comment: if i put row outside loop it put 10 col in a row.because loop count is 10

Comment: That's why you need to add the `col-6` class to the partial. Please see the following to understand how the Bootstrap grid system works: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Comment: can u write a code below. .what do u want to say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
<div class="flex">
  <div class="row">
    @foreach (var product in Model.Products)
    {
      <div class="col-6">
        @Html.Partial("_MediumProductWrap", product) // Col
      </div>
    }
  </div>
</div>
```

The bootstrap grid system uses a 12 column grid, so setting the div around your partial to have `col-6` will make the products display as a grid with 2 columns.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the flex wrapper div around the whole thing. Please see my updated answer. Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t1ya8nfc/